# How do I logout my Discordbot in JS savely with a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I built a basic Discord bot which I want to go offline when I type the corresponding command on the Discord server "!logout". I searched for answers, but those who used discord.js weren't responsed...

If I use `client.logout()` it throws an error and crashs with

> TypeError: client.logout is not a function

and it won't even call my error function.
Maybe the answer is simple but I can't find it anywhere.

Here's my basic code:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"],
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready');
});

client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!logout'){
    
      client.logout(() => {
        msg.reply('couldn^t go offline')
      })
    }
  
  
})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the function `<Client>#destroy()`

If you want to exit Node.js, you can then use `process.exit(0)`

[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=destroy)

Answer (score 0):

```js
process.exit(0)
```

From the docs:

> `process.exit([exitcode])`
> Ends the process with the specified code. If
> omitted, exit uses the 'success' code 0.
>
> To exit with a 'failure' code:
>
> process.exit(1); The shell that executed node should see the exit code
> as 1.

Comment: if this is the only way, i'll use ist, ty :)